# Bindings not working with dictionary if dictionary was filled late

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a WPF app. I'm using MVVM pattern. I have a dictionary:

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase
 {
        public static Dictionary<string, Action> Permissions { get; set; }

        ...
 }
```

and i want to bind it's values to visibility of menu items like so:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="systemMenuItem" Header="System" Visibility="{Binding Permissions[systemMenuItem].CanBeShow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">...</MenuItem>
```

To fill this dictionary i need window build visual tree because elements of dictionary contains information from window MenuItem's. If i will create dictionary before InitializeComponent i will get an exception that there is no key with value `systemMenuItem` because `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` returns zero elements. If i will do it on `Loaded` event i will get normal filled dictionary but binding not working in that case. How can i fill my dictionary before window will be shown to user and get information from MenuItems? And how can i make my binding work in that case? The window is the main and startup.

Comment: If you bind to dictionaries that may change you should use a bindable dictionary implementation.

Comment: To expand on @H.B.: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

Comment: I tried it know but result is the same. I'm just changed the type of dictionary and everything else is the same. Binding still not working on `Loaded` and exception is thrown if i am creating ObservableDictionary before `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: as a general rule using dictionaries for binding is a bad idea, this is probably why MS never created Observable Dictionary as part of the .Net framework, you're best bet would be to create a Permission class and then have an Observable Collection of them, this will give you both collection binding and change binding on the Permission

Comment: @MikeT, can you please provide some simple example of your approach?

Comment: @YuryKerbitskov done see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, i want to tell thank you to everyone who helped me with their suggestions to find solution.
I have created `SilentDictionary` class and using it instead of `Dictionary`:

```
public class SilentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
        where TValue : class, new()
    {
        protected IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary;

        public SilentDictionary()
        {
            Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                TValue item;
                if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item))
                    return item;
                else
                {
                    item = new TValue();
                    Add(key, item);
                    return item;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                Add(key, value);
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionary.Count;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionary.IsReadOnly;
            }
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionary.Keys;
            }
        }

        public ICollection<TValue> Values
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionary.Values;
            }
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }

        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            TValue item;
            if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item))
            {                
                Type t = typeof(TValue);
                var props = t.GetProperties();
                foreach (var p in props)
                    p.SetValue(item, p.GetValue(value));
            }
            else
                Dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            Dictionary.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return Dictionary.Contains(item);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            Dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return Dictionary.Remove(item);
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            return Dictionary.Remove(key);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
        {
            return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)Dictionary).GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

The main idea of this class is not throw exception when `InitializeComponent` is in progress. It gives me an opportunity to create an instance of dictionary before binding will try to get value from it. This is what is going on in the main window constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ViewModelBase.Permissions = new SilentDictionary<string, Action>();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Now binding have no `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`. Binding have connection with my static `SilentDictionary` instance. Next step is to make static notify property change for dictionary:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    protected static SilentDictionary<string, Action> _permissions;

    public static SilentDictionary<string, Action> Permissions
    {
        get { return _permissions; }
        set
        {
            _permissions = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }  

    public static event EventHandler PermissionsChanged;

    protected static void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        EventHandler temp = Volatile.Read(ref PermissionsChanged);
        PermissionsChanged?.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
    }

    // other code
}
```

And, finally, i can bind to this dictionary as i planned at the beginning:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="systemMenuItem" Header="Система" Visibility="{Binding Permissions[systemMenuItem].CanBeShown, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
```

And everything works well as expected.

Answer (score 3):

as a general rule using dictionaries for binding is a bad idea, this is probably why MS never created Observable Dictionary as part of the .Net framework, you're best bet would be to create a Permission class and then have an Observable Collection of them, this will give you both collection binding and change binding on the Permission

**Note: this uses C#6 so if you are on a earlier version you may need to tweak it**

Example

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Permissions}">
            <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding CanBeShow, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Action}"/>
                </Style>
            </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </Menu>
        <Grid/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

View Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        //some dummy data
        Permissions.Add(new Permission()
        {
            Name = "Open",
            CanBeShow = true,
            Action = ApplicationCommands.Open
        });
        Permissions.Add(new Permission()
        {
            Name = "Save",
            CanBeShow = false,
            Action = ApplicationCommands.Save
        });
        Permissions.Add(new Permission()
        {
            Name = "Delete",
            CanBeShow = true,
            Action = ApplicationCommands.Delete
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Permission> Permissions { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Permission>();
    //notice no set you want to change the content of the collection not the collection
}

public class Permission:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    private bool canBeShow;

    public bool CanBeShow
    {
        get { return canBeShow; }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CanBeShow)));
            canBeShow = value;
        }
    }


    private ICommand action;
    public ICommand Action
    {
        get { return action; }
        set {
            action = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Action)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

however if you are trying to implement some kind of security on Menu actions,
then preferred way of doing this would be to override the ICommand to create a Custom Command that will look up it's own permissions and expose them as properties with out going near the View

```
public class PermissionCommand:INotifyPropertyChanged,ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    public bool CanBeShow
    {
        get
        {
             //Check permissions for CanBeShow here 
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //Check permissions for Execution here 
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // perform action here
    }
    //you will need to trigger the events when the permissions change
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! It is interesting solution and i will think about using it in my next project but for now i have found another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a multi-value converter like this:

```
public class ElementPermissionToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Action> permissions = values.OfType<Dictionary<string, Action>>().FirstOrDefault();
        FrameworkElement element = values.OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (permissions != null && element != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Name))
        {
            Action action;

            if (permissions.TryGetValue(element.Name, out action))
            {
                return action.CanBeShown ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use it in XAML like this:

```
 <MenuItem x:Name="systemMenuItem" Header="System">
    <MenuItem.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ElementPermissionToVisibilityConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Permissions"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </MenuItem.Visibility>
</MenuItem>
```

This will provide several advantages not least of which would be to re-evaluate the binding if the Permissions property changes.

Obviously this is quite verbose but you could wrap the binding into a MenuItem Style so you only need define it once.

Comment: It's working for the first time. But when i want to change value it's not working. I've tried `Dictionary` and `ObservableDictionary`. Is it possible with this solution to solve it? For example, on `Loaded` event i'm doing something like this: `ViewModelBase.Permissions.Add("systemMenuItem", new Security.ActionBased.Action());
            ViewModelBase.Permissions["systemMenuItem"].CanBeShow = true;`

Comment: After any changes to permissions, call PropertyChanged for the Permissions property. Should re-evaluate the permission and update the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the solution1 It is working, but i made another one based on all of your recomendations and advises. I will write it as an answere.